# Multi redis connection issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

I am trying to connect my project with two Redis connection but I got

```
Consider defining a bean named 'redisTemplate' in your configuration.
```

I don't know if my code is correct but this is my code config, my spring boot version 2.4.2 :

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private EditorialRedisPropertyConfiguration editorialRedisConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRedisPropertyConfiguration productRedisConfiguration;

    @Bean(name = "editorialRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, ?> editorialRedisTemplate(
            @Qualifier(value = "redisEditorialConnectionFactory") RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisEditorialConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean(name = "productRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, ?> productRedisTemplate(
            @Qualifier(value = "redisProductConnectionFactory") RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return template;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> initJackson2JsonRedisSerializer() {
        .  ..
    }

    @Bean(name = "redisEditorialConnectionFactory")
    @Primary
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisEditorialConnectionFactory() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean(name = "redisProductConnectionFactory")
    @Primary
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisProductConnectionFactory() {
         .....
    }

}
```

with application config :

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your application code but this can be fixed by simply creating another bean, given you don't use that you're free to create it from any redis config.

```
    @Bean(name = "productRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, ?> redisTemplate(
            @Qualifier(value = "redisProductConnectionFactory") RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return template;
    }
```